# Enhanced ecommerce data pushed from iframe not sent to Analytics

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a popup with a iframe that loads product list (e.g, subscribe.html). In subscribe.html template I check if page is opened in an iframe and send product impressions to parent dataLayer then. Here's the code:

```
<script>
var data = {
    ecommerce: {
        currencyCode: 'GBP',
        impressions: [{
            id: 'product_1',
            name: 'product 1 name',
            list: window.top === window ? 'Traditional' : 'Light Box',
            position: 0,
            price: 10
        }]
    }
};

(window.top === window ? window : window.parent).dataLayer.push(data);
</script>
```

But, when popup is open, the data from dataLayer is not sent to GA. 
My Universal Analytics tag is set up as following:

```
Track Type: page view
Firing triggers: all pages
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the data is pushed only after the pageview on the main page already has executed (and you need an interaction hit to send ecommerce data). I suggest you add a custom event to the data and use that for a trigger that fires an Google Analytics event with the e-commerce data attached.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but even when I click on product in iframe that should send the `addToCart` event to parent.dataLayer, the data is not sent.

Answer (score 0):

iframes are different, separate pages, and require their own GTM container. If they're on different domains it becomes a real headache (http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/iframe-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-tag-manager/), but otherwise you should just be able to do it reasonably easily by putting a Google Tag Manager container inside the iframe.

However, you will have to keep an eye out for any extra tags that the in-frame container might be throwing. For example, if you use the same container as your regular site, it likely has a Page View tag as a default; you may want to tell this not to activate when within an iframe, lest you double count people.